# Neosnippet expands to "options head"

Tags: snippets

I am creating my firsts neosnippet-snippets in c.snip, it looks like that:

```
snippet head
  options head
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // ${1:TITLE}
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  ${0:TARGET}

  //// END OF $1

snippet stdlib
  options head
  alias std
  #include <stdlib.h>${0}
```

The first snippet expands correctly while the seconds expands to:

```
  options head
  alias std
  #include <stdlib.h>
```

Why so?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you **indent** the snippet options ('keywords'), by not following the help example (`:h neosnippet-snippet-syntax`). So, you need:

```
snippet stdlib
options head
alias std
    #include<stdlib.h>${0}
```

BTW, I'm not sure if `${0}` is needed at all, in this example.